# How to import external .js files into commands.js? [Office.js Excell]

Tags: office-js

what is the proper way of importing a function that is in a different `.js` script into the `commands.js` script for an Office Excell Ribbon add-in?

Here is my `commands.html` file:

```
<!--
    "commands.html"
    HTML file importing the necessary scripts, especially commands.js where
    button presses are mapped.
-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script src="commands.js" type="module"></script>
```

Here is my `commands.js` file

```
/*
  "commands.js"
  All top-level functions that are mapped to button presses on the ribbon
  are and should be in this file. Function names are the same as the IDs of 
  the buttons they are mapped to (with underscored instead of dashes).
*/

import * as tools from "./scripts/native/tools.js"

Office.initialize = function() { 
  /*
    Initialize Office function. Has to be called here.
  */
} 

console.log(tools.char_to_underscore("test32"))
```

Here is the function I would like to import in `tools.js`:

```
/*
    "tools.js"
    A collection of functions that help with certain problems.
*/

export function char_to_underscore(string) {
    /*
        Replaces a set of characters in a string with underscores.
    */
    var replacement_list = [/ /g, ".", "\\", "%", "/", "\n", "-", "(", ")", "|"];
    for (var replace in replacement_list) {
        string = string.replace(replacement_list[replace], "_");
    }
    return string;
}
```

Here is my project directory:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZyCK.png)

VSCode seems to find these files perfectly fine, but when I launch the add-in I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
logger — index.js:551 (https://localhost:3000/scripts/native/tools.js)
```

I have tried almost everything I can think of and nothing seems to resolve this issue. Am I missing something here? It is unsustainable for large ribbon projects to have all the source code in one file.

Comment: Are you using a `<Runtimes>` element in the manifest? Also, based on this article, what browser webview is being used on your machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: Hi Rick, I am not using the `<Runtimes>` element in my manifest. I generated the project with the yeoman generator and added a custom tab element to add buttons to my ribbon. As for for browser, I am developing on a Mac so based on that article the web view is Safari/Not Applicable.

Comment: See what happens if you try this: `import * as tools from "../commands/scripts/native/tools.js"` or this: `import * as tools from "/scripts/native/tools.js"` (no period). Also, what happens if you don't have any import of tools.js at all and just call `console.log(char_to_underscore("test32"))` (no "tools/")?  Finally, could you give us the loaders and plugin sections of your webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "launch the add-in"? Do you mean start the server? Or press a button on the ribbon? Or something else?

Comment: FWIW, I've duplicated your code and folder structure, and I'm not having this problem. I don't get the error. The add-in runs without error and I can press the add-in command button without error and the `char_to_underscore` method runs fine. I'm working on Windows.

Comment: Hi @Rick, thanks for the comments. What I mean by start the plugin is I press a custom button on the ribbon after I have side loaded the app with `npm start`. Here is my webpack.config.js: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ANd9saCV). Could you maybe upload a zip of your duplicated code so that I can test it on my machine please?

Comment: Get it here: [ExcelJSaddin](https://github.com/Rick-Kirkham/ExcelJSaddin). See the Readme for instructions.

Comment: Your method also works me @Rick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. The only method I found that works for the purpose I desire is the following:

- Instead of mapping ribbon buttons in the `commands.js` file, rather do it in `commands.html` with code being written in a `<script>` tag as follows:

```
<script>
    async function button_x_pressed(event) { 
    console.log(char_to_underscore("f%%%"));
    console.log(return_sample_values());
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        let range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        range.format.fill.color = "Blue";
        await context.sync();
    });
    event.completed(); // must be called (signals to Excell that the process/event is completed)
    }
</script>
```

- In `commands.html`, import external .js files as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/native/tools.js"></script>
```

- The `button_x_pressed` function can then find the `char_to_underscore` function although the autocomplete in VScode does not.
- The only code in `commands.js` is the following:

```
Office.initialize = function() { 
  /*
    Initialize Office function. Has to be called here.
  */
}
```

This can most likely also be moved to the in-file `<script>` in `commands.html` but I decided to keep it here to have something in this autogenerated file.

- My method comes down to mapping buttons to functions in `commands.hmtl` and calling external scripts in those functions that perform the desired action of the ribbon button.

Comment: This should not be necessary. See the link to the sample in GitHub that I put in my latest comment to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Rick, I'll take a look at your code.